# grep в конструкции if

Tags: linux, bash, docker, grep

Разбираюсь с bash'ем
Хочу написать скрипт для работы с докером, столкнулся с непониманием работы синтаксиса bash.
Пример скрипта такой:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(docker ps)
container=container_name
if $result | grep $container
then
echo "$container is work"
fi
```

Если контейнер с именем container_name запущен то по идее мы должны пройти условие, но получается такая ошибка:

```
./mscript.sh: line 4: CONTAINER: command not found
```

Comment: if $(echo ${result} | grep ${container})

Comment: @AndrioSkur та же ошибка

Comment: `if grep -q "${container}" <<<"${result}"` симпатишней будет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все штатно. просто сделайте подстановку всех переменных и посмотрите что получается. bash пытается выполнить $result как команду. Скорее всего Вы имели ввиду такое

```
echo $result | grep $container
```

Comment: Да условие сработало но теперь в консоли я получаю еще и содержание $result, как можно этого избежать?

Comment: например, добавив ключик `-q` для grep

Comment: да вы правы, спасибо большое.

Comment: Похоже, лучше переадресовать вывод `grep` в `/dev/null`. [*Portable shell scripts should avoid both `-q` and `-s` and should redirect standard and error output to `/dev/null` instead.*](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).

Comment: возможно. Каждый раз когда я встречаю подобное, я задаюсь вопросом "а в каком году это написано и встречу ли я систему, на которой это будет работать по другому"

Comment: В общем случае я согласен с @WiktorStribizew, попробуйте, например, Debian (dash), хотя в данном случае я бы использовал (и использую!) *-q*.

Comment: о, dash, это нечто. Когда я первый раз его в федоре увидел, я был в шоке, почему почти ни один мой скрипт не работает. Но потом его допилили до рабочего состояния, а мои скрипты начали работать.

Answer (score 1):

Дружище, изучите [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering), то что вы делаете через `if`, `grep` и т.д. делается внутри команды `docker ps`:

```
$ docker ps --no-trunc -af name="^*$" -f status="running" --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Status}}"
0c9b82211c4da46d2af47f30fd1f90150173b70d29574030e6eadc399c9f58a8: Up 3 days
32b8a98772a4b0520252aba1eee944251c72c404d5ddef0a71f59f82d385926f: Up 2 weeks
f394c4b1dbec886c75880ae217a6243dde44ed4dc81d7c0cea533339140c5d01: Up 3 days
2e02efb775c34b945e97dbdea41da9776aa05c83789520eaf32544dad8980db1: Up 2 weeks
451524ce8dc85a63d60f561b436c646ba8f2141346a14a21d1c16709cbed6441: Up 2 weeks
e0aa486fa921109c512640a49d07aa1b33a72ab9d64446614cbc44e475f26848: Up 2 weeks
```

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле мне надо не просто вывести инфу по контейнеру а сделать что то еще с ним